# Get Scheduled time from scheduled posts of a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I get the publishing time for a scheduled post in a facebook page?

In the graph API I only get created time and updated time, but I can't find a publishing time, to know when the post its going to be publish.

Comment: Why was this post downvoted? This is not well-referenced in the documentation if referenced at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(On behalf of OP)

After some weeks i figured it out:

```
  <?php
//Get Facebook SDK Object
$config = array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID,
  'secret' => API_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

//Create Query
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT message,scheduled_publish time FROM stream 
        WHERE is_published=0 AND scheduled_publish_time!=''",
);

//Run Query
$result = $facebook->api($params);
?>
```

And done, that will show you the same posts that activity log in the facebook page.